# Posting an url i"m getting Invalid request

Tags: objective-c, ios, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

What would be the reason for getting Invalid Request when we are posting an URL to server in iOS SDK. the URL what i am sending is correct and the data what I'm posting is also correct.
I tried in RestClient also even though I'm getting same error Invalid Request in that also.
Can any one help me what would be the reason for it.
Thanks in advance.

```
- (NSURLConnection *) executeAsyncHttpPost :(NSString *) baseURL :(NSString *) method 
                                       :(id) jsonParams :(int)callerTag
{

   NSLog(@"jsonParams: %@", jsonParams);

   NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", baseURL];
   urlstr = [urlstr stringByAppendingFormat:method];
   NSLog(@"urlstr: %@", urlstr);
   NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonParams length]];

   NSURL *pUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:pUrl];
   NSData *requestData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[jsonParams dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

   NSString* myString;
   myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setHTTPBody: requestData];


   self.tag = callerTag;


   return [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegateResponder];
}
```

Comment: can you share some code.. so that we code clear your doubts

Comment: can u say what is the reason for Getting Invalid Requset

Comment: can you share the jsonParams which you are printing on console

Comment: jsonParams: "jsonRequest="{"methodName":"CheckUserExist","username":"giriraj.vyas@dotsquares.com","password":"233444"}

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are posting might be invalid. Please validate it using [this](http://jsonlint.com/). There should be no character outside the **{ }**.

Just post the following string instead of the current JSON

**EDIT:**

```
{"jsonRequest" :{"methodName":"CheckUserExist","username":"giriraj.vyas@dotsquares‌​.com","password":"233444"}}
```

Comment: i tried in that way also no use we are getting same Invalid Request

Comment: could you share the **new** jsonParams you are getting now

Comment: try passing the new edited json in the answer and let me know if it still doesn't work please reply

Comment: My New jsonParams: {"methodName":"CheckUserExist","username":"giriraj.vyas@dotsquares.com","password":"123456789"}

Comment: I got one doubt ,if server may be down also we will get Invalid Request?

Comment: No it would not give Invalid Request, there is some thing wrong in your json, use the new edited json I have posted and check

Comment: what is the json you are using on the RestClient. Can you share that here.

Comment: {"jsonRequest" :{"methodName":"CheckUserExist","username":"giriraj.vyas@dotsquares‌​.com","password":"233444"}}

Comment: set this string as it is  to the jsonParams value and then check if you are still getting 'Invalid Request'